# Get play position of audio buffer in web audio API

Tags: web-audio-api

I am making a browser based DJ app, and need an indicator to show how much of an audio track(audio buffer) has played on a waveform. I have a waveform but cant get the current position.

Answer (score 0):

The `Web Audio API` uses a common time frame to synchronise all running and scheduled sounds, which can be read from `AudioContext.currentTime`. You can store the timestamp of when you start your sound and measure the elapsed time while the sound is played. By this you get the position in seconds. If you need the frame index position of the `AudioBuffer` you can multiply the elapsed time by the `sampleRate` of the `AudioBuffer`.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Time Elapsed Demo</title>
<script>
const audioCtx = new AudioContext()

async function startSample() {
  const output = document.getElementById("output")

  const response = await fetch('test.wav')
  const sample = await response.arrayBuffer()
  const audioBuffer = await audioCtx.decodeAudioData(sample)
  const sampleRate = audioBuffer.sampleRate

  const sourceNode = audioCtx.createBufferSource()
  sourceNode.buffer = audioBuffer
  sourceNode.connect(audioCtx.destination)

  let ended = false
  sourceNode.onended = () => { ended = true }

  const startTime = audioCtx.currentTime + 0.01
  sourceNode.start(startTime)

  function showTimeElapsed() {
    if (ended == false) {
      elapsed = audioCtx.currentTime - startTime;
  
      if (elapsed >= 0) {
        output.innerHTML =
          "Time elapsed: " + elapsed.toFixed(3) + ", " +
          "Frame index: " + (sampleRate * elapsed).toFixed(0)
      }

      requestAnimationFrame(showTimeElapsed)
    }
  }

  showTimeElapsed()
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="start" onclick="startSample()">Start Sample</button>
<p>
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```